# Identifying several fonts

Tags: fonts, typography, logo, font-identification, typefaces

I am trying to identify several fonts but hitting a brick wall.

Can anyone help me identify these fonts please?

[image: AFE]

[image: Arcgitectes.ch]

[image: electrosuisse]

[image: UPIAV]

[image]

Comment: Yeah...I have tried whatthefont.com, intelligent.com and I also have the app "Font Genius" but the results are not very encouraging. Something or many things are off! I think UPIAV us Zurich, but not exactly! And I think Architectes.ch is Frutiger, but again, not exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afe - [Neuropol X](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/neuropol-x/) (*a* and *e* have been modified and by the way this *was* identified with [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/))

Architectes.ch - [Frutiger Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/frutiger/)

electrosuisse and UPIAV (both) - [TheSans Plain](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/singles/lucasfonts/thesans_plain/)

Comment: My only hesitation is Neuropol X for age, as the f also seems modified, so I think this may be yet another font. But otherwise, the rest seem to be exact!

Comment: To me, *f* looks like a precise match to Neuropol X Exp... Maybe with an added stroke to make the weight slightly bolder.

Comment: I have added a new image above showing Neuropol X isn't quite the same. If you look at the slope of the curve of the F, you will see what I mean. There are too many differences between Neuropol X and the logo font...although it could all be manual modifications, but I somehow doubt it.

Comment: Hmm, are we talking about the same typeface? The link I've provided leads to MyFonts where the font previews look exactly like afe's logo but completely different to what you've just added.

Comment: Just deleted the reference to Eurostile in afe because the larger version of the logo shows it's not correct

Comment: The larger version is just a scaled up from a poorly saved gif that was embedded in a PDF!!! Not sure what the correct font is.

Comment: Also, I had accidentally activated Neuropolitical which is also on my system...so sorry, you are correct...Neuropol is pretty close.

Comment: The second font in afe could be anything "Helvetica-like". It's too small to tell exactly.

Comment: I tried Helvetica, and seems to be pretty close. Thank you for all your help.